# Не могу положить JSONArray в ArrayList<Custom>

Tags: java, android, json

есть код

```
 @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray values = response.getJSONArray("melodies");
                toList(values);
                Model_Melodies melodies = new Model_Melodies();
                melodies.setMelodies(melodiesList);
                artist=melodiesList.get(0);
                txtDisplay.setText("Response => " + artist);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}

public static List toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {

    melodiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (array!=null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            melodiesList.add((Model_Melodies.Melodies) array.get(i));
        }
    }
    return melodiesList;
}
```

в данной строке:

```
melodiesList.add((Model_Melodies.Melodies) array.get(i));
```

вылетает СlassCastExcep, подскажите как положить правильно данные в мой класс??

пример класса Model_Melodies

```
public class Model_Melodies {
private ArrayList<Melodies> mMelodies;

public ArrayList<Melodies> getMelodies() {
    return mMelodies;
}

public void setMelodies(ArrayList<Melodies> melodies) {
    mMelodies = melodies;
}

static class Melodies{
    private String picUrl;
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String demoUrl;

    public String getPicUrl() {
        return picUrl;
    }

    public void setPicUrl(String picUrl) {
        this.picUrl = picUrl;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getDemoUrl() {
        return demoUrl;
    }

    public void setDemoUrl(String demoUrl) {
        this.demoUrl = demoUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: А где обьявление melodiesList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно, а как он должен привести строку к классу?

Для начала необходимо разобрать данные. Из `JSONArray` достать `JSONObject`. Затем создать новый объект класса `Model_Melodies.Melodies` и в него сложить данные из `JSONObject`. А затем этот класс положить в Ваш `ArrayList`.

Comment: а зачем создавать еще класс? разве нельзя сложить данные в Melodies? там ведь все поля прописаны, нельзя ли напрямую в них кидать?

Comment: @Сергей, объект класса, непрвильно выразился.

Comment: спасибо  VAndrJ.разобрался!